# UIButton in navigation item does not respond to click

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, swift2, uinavigationitem

i am trying to add three button to the navigation item and i wrote these code:

```
let customNavigationItemView : UIView = UIView()
let trendbutton : UIButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
size = myString.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)])
size.width = size.width * 1.5
nearbybutton.frame.size = size
...
let nearbybutton : UIButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
...
let squarebutton : UIButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
...
trendbutton.frame.origin = CGPointMake(-trendbutton.frame.size.width - nearbybutton.frame.size.width / 2, 0)
...
customNavigationItemView.addSubview(trendbutton)
customNavigationItemView.addSubview(nearbybutton)
customNavigationItemView.addSubview(squarebutton)
self.navigationItem.titleView = customNavigationItemView

trendbutton.addTarget(self, action:  "circleNavigationBar_trendButton_clickUp:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
nearbybutton.addTarget(self, action: "circleNavigationBar_nearbyButton_clickUp:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
squarebutton.addTarget(self, action: "circleNavigationBar_squareButton_clickUp:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

and this:

```
func circleNavigationBar_trendButton_clickUp(sender : UIButton) {
    print("trend click")
}
```

but when i click the button in the navigation item, print nothing.
anyone can tell me the reason? thank you all the same.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `frame` of your `customNavigationItemView` to the a size that contains the 3 buttons. Otherwise it has a zero size and does not pass touch events to its subviews because they occur outside of the view.

So if your buttons have a size of 20 x 20 and are touching each other this will work:

```
let customNavigationItemView : UIView = UIView()
customNavigationItemView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 20)

let trendbutton : UIButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
trendbutton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)
...
let nearbybutton : UIButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
nearbybutton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 0, 20, 20)
...
let squarebutton : UIButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
squarebutton.frame = CGRectMake(40, 0, 20, 20)
```

Comment: actually i set the frame like this and i updated the question, but it does not work. thank you all the same.

Answer (score 0):

i think maybe i found the answer, i changed my code like this:

```
trendbutton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, trendSize.width, trendSize.height)
nearbybutton.frame = CGRectMake(trendSize.width, 0, nearbySize.width, nearbySize.height)
squarebutton.frame = CGRectMake(trendSize.width + nearbySize.width, 0, squareSize.width, squareSize.height)
customNavigationItemView?.frame = CGRectMake(self.circleTable_tableView.frame.width / 2, 0, trendSize.width + nearbySize.width + squareSize.width, max(trendSize.height, nearbySize.height, squareSize.height))
```

it works great now but i do not understand the difference between these two ways to set frame:
one is:

```
someView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,10,10)
```

the other one is:

```
someView.frame.origin = CGPointMake(0,0) 
someView.frame.size = CGSizeMake(10,10)
```